# How does Huygens' Principle follow from the fact that the Green's function for the wave equation is a spherically expanding disturbance?

Tags: diffraction, greens-functions, huygens-principle

In simple words, the statement that the Green's function for the wave equation is a spherically expanding wave means that waves radiate spherically outwards from an impulsive disturbance. This much is clear. But in situations where there is no impulsive source (for example, along the length of a finite-size slit illuminated from one side), diffraction still occurs. How does one explain this using the Green's function of the wave equation?

Comment: Good question. Another difference to water waves is the fact, that along an intersection line behind the double slit the chrests of the waves are moving to the right and to the left. For light there is a standstill of the intensity distribution.